# running clang scan-build with g++ on linux

Tags: c++, clang++, scan-build

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        void foo() const;
};

void A::foo() const {}

std::unique_ptr<A> foo2()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> pa(new A());
    return pa;
}

void
foo()
{
    const A& ra = *foo2();
    ra.foo();
}

int
main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use clang's scan-build:

```
scan-build g++ --std=c++11 unique_ptr.cpp
```

This program compiles and runs fine with g++.
I am using CentOS and clang3.8 and g++4.8.5.

Error Message:

```
 error: no type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'
 std::unique_ptr<A> foo2()
 ~~~~~^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
scan-build g++ -std=c++11 unique_ptr.cpp
```

Instead of:

```
scan-build g++ --std=c++11 unique_ptr.cpp
```

`-std` works (while `--std` doesn't) because `scan-build` checks specifically for the `-std` flag.

In [`clang/tools/scan-build/libexec/ccc-analyzer`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/19b977bcdf62a9f6fca2c115fd85d2508f4a818b/tools/scan-build/libexec/ccc-analyzer#L632-L635):

```
if ($Arg =~ /^-std=/) {
  push @CompileOpts,$Arg;
  next;
}
```